# login to http website java

Tags: java, http

I am trying to login to a http website for the first time and I am having a hard time understanding the proper format for sending arguments. I have looked at other examples and they don't seem to work for me so I thought I would see if someone can explain this to me. At this point my code seems to do absolutely nothing but here it is...

```
HttpURLConnection url= (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://www.myameego.com/index2.php?do=login").openConnection();
url.setDoOutput(true);
url.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(url.getOutputStream());
writer.write("X-Mapping-fjhppofk=6A991610BA398B3A39F4B491D5382BB4;
PHPSESSID=kbo25e08t3qvu08l1shkq8kk94; userName=coled; pass=ed45d626b07112a8a501d9672f3b92796a6754b8d8d9cb4c617fec9774889220; clientID=129; X-Mapping-fjhppofk=DCE62FE972E1EF2F12D0060EC74C3681; PHPSESSID=ukeo21oldb5pqsntu7kl8j3b96");
writer.flush();
```

I downloaded an http sniffer thinking that I could read what the browser was sending. that is how I got the write() line, it is the cookie that was sent by explorer. I also viewed the source code for the login screen and found a block of code near the bottom that looks like its responsible for login.

http://www.myameego.com/index2.php?do=login

Can someone tell me how I would go about hooking into this interface I don't understand how this works. if it helps this is the full packet from my manual login through the browser. I got it from my http sniffer.

```
Host Name: www.myameego.com
Method: POST
Path: /index2.php?do=login
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; NP06)
Response Code: 302
Response String: found
Content Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://www.myameego.com/index.php?do=login
Transfer Encoding: chunked
Server: Apache
Content Length: 17817
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Location: /Ameego/index.php
Cookie: X-Mapping-fjhppofk=6A991610BA398B3A39F4B491D5382BB4; PHPSESSID=kbo25e08t3qvu08l1shkq8kk94; userName=coled; pass=ed45d626b07112a8a501d9672f3b92796a6754b8d8d9cb4c617fec9774889220; clientID=129; X-Mapping-fjhppofk=DCE62FE972E1EF2F12D0060EC74C3681; PHPSESSID=ukeo21oldb5pqsntu7kl8j3b96
URL: http://www.myameego.com/index2.php?do=login
```

How can I make a packet like the one above? any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I Looked into that link you posted and the http sniffer shows that the POST request is being called but the cookie line doesn't match up with that of the manual browser request.

```
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://www.myameego.com/index2.php?do=login").openConnection();
    httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","UTF-8");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; NP06)");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    String info = String.format("user=%s&coled=%s",URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8"),URLEncoder.encode("coled","UTF-8"));
    info += String.format("pass=%s&MYPASS=%s",URLEncoder.encode("pass","UTF-8"),URLEncoder.encode("MYPASS","UTF-8"));
    info += String.format("clientID=%s&129=%s",URLEncoder.encode("clientID","UTF-8"),URLEncoder.encode("129","UTF-8"));
    info += String.format("login=%s&Sign In=%s",URLEncoder.encode("login","UTF-8"),URLEncoder.encode("Sign In","UTF-8"));
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",info);
    OutputStream output = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
    output.write(info.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    int x;
    while((x = httpConnection.getInputStream().read()) != -1)System.out.print((char)x);
```

my Cookie:
user=user&coled=coledpass=pass&MYPASS=MYPASSclientID=clientID&129=129login=login&Sign In=Sign+In

browsers cookie:
X-Mapping-fjhppofk=6A991610BA398B3A39F4B491D5382BB4; PHPSESSID=112tg9i4afau5i382hui705553

anyone know what I may be missing here?

Comment: Please post any errors that you might be coming across, so it would be easier to understand the problem

Comment: And why didn't you try to dump the whole request incl. all HTTP headers (servers may check this)? Btw - are you allowed to do this? Are you sure you can reuse all those magic numbers? Any idea how HTTP works (your out stream does not make sense)?

Comment: I had not seen that link before it looks like it helped a lot. my earlier code wasn't even sending out a packet thanks. Im not sure how to get the PHPSESSID or what the X-Mapping thing is all about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jsoup this should be simple like this:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.myameego.com/index2.php?do=login")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://www.myameego.com/index2.php?do=login")
        .data("user", "login")
        .data("pass", "password")
        .data("clientID", "123456")
        .cookies(response.cookies())
        .post();
```

Gathered with [Google Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)

[image: request]

[image: cookies used]

Comment: how do you then view the webpage?

Comment: It is sending me a list of requirements I think???

I know this website runs on flashplayer is this going to be a problem for me?

Comment: ohh oh I got it working. it gives me the list of options on the webpage immediately following the post() call. how do I make a get call after this?\

Comment: Sorry. that wasn't clear. The website normally displays a list of buttons e.g. Up Coming Shifts, Message Board. Each of these buttons is a link to a webpage that displays the information. I want to select one of these buttons how do I do about doing this?

Comment: This is next question ;) Use Google Developer Tools and get link to other site, then do: Jsoup.connect(otherPageUrl).cookies(response.cookies).get();